# q service in node.js confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't understand below part

```
var q = require("q"),
BlogPost = require("../models/blogPost");

module.exports = {
    getAllPosts: getAllPosts
};

function getAllPosts() {
    var deferred = q.defer();

    BlogPost
        .find({})
        .sort("-date")
        .exec(function(error, posts) {
            if (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(posts);
            }
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I found above code in controller, but can't understand it. Why at the end we use return deferred.promise? How would I use the `getAllPosts` later? Can't we just return the posts objects?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: @ceejayoz is promises a part of javascript? why we can't just return the posts object?

Comment: Yes, Promises are part of JavaScript. You can't return the posts object probably because whatever the `BlogPost` service is doing is asynchronous.

Comment: Here you can read the Q documentation on `defer()` https://github.com/kriskowal/q#using-deferreds

Comment: @ceejayoz what if I do `BlogPost.find({}).sort("-date").exec(callback);` and call the `BlogPost(function(err,posts){ //get my posts here })`

Comment: @NingSia We have no idea, you haven't shared what `BlogPost`'s code is. The way it's implemented is likely the sensible way, and you just need to understand Promises and asynchronous actions.

Comment: @ceejayoz https://github.com/aspnetde/thomasbandt.com/blob/master/data/models/blogPost.js

Comment: Probably should read: [How do I return the value from an asynchronous callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Answer (score 1):

You would consume a function that returns a promise like so:

```
var getAllPosts = require('./your-module-name.js').getAllPosts;

getAllPosts()
 .then(function(posts) {
  //successfully process the posts
 })
 .catch(function(err) {
  //handle the error
 })
 .finally(function(){
  //clean up anything you need to...
 })
```

Comment: can I use multiple then? is the order matter? can I put `catch` above `then`?

Comment: You can put the catch above the then if you'd like.  You can do catch.then.catch.then as many times as you want... just return what you need to from each section in the promise chain.

Answer (score 0):

> `Promise` is the just representation of the asynchronous result.

It has three states:

> 1-> success
>
> -> Error
>
> -> Pending
>
> `deferred` is a just object of promise and it returns after processing one of above state.
>
> We can use `javascript` code without promise but sometimes we have to give it to make our code `execute` as `asynchronous way`.

That's why we use promise

Comment: so basically Promise is just a neater version of callback?

Comment: Yes, it provides the better way to work with `synchronous way` nature in the `asynchronous` world!

Comment: Yes, it can be handle with `callback` but normally we avoid `callback` to safe from `callback hell`.